# running multiple commands in windows command line

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

how can I run multiple commands at once from windows command line?
In *nix environment I can do:

```
export VAR=foo; echo $VAR
```

The closest way I was able to find is this:

```
set VAR=foo & echo %VAR%
```

however when I "echo" the VAR is not set. I need all commands to be executed under the same process

Comment: Put them into a .bat/.cmd file. That'll run inside a single cmd.exe instance.

Comment: I cant do that. I'm running those commands remotely (and they are generated) and I have to run them like this: $ cmd /c commands

Comment: In the future, it'd be helpful to mention this sort of detail in advance.

Comment: batch file is not they wanted to do. You know that the sequence of commands works in one environment but not in the other so you very well understand the differences between environments. You do not ask to install Linux but you demand that asking people warned that Linux is not acceptable to them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`cmd /c call set VAR=foo & echo %VAR%` - this worked ok i.e.   set is called with "call set"
.You can set call before each of the commands.

Comment: In fact, it's enough to put `call` just before `echo`, and `cmd` is not needed either.

Comment: Well, I don't know why but this isn't working for me. The result of echo is always "%VAR%".

Comment: Andriy M: "cmd /c" is needed for me because it is a remote call so i have to put those commands as a parameter to cmd.exe

Comment: what if you set the expression after /c swithc in brackets?  ->
`CMD /c "call set var=foo & call cmd /c call echo %var%"`

Comment: Thank you. Whole trick was in calling echo in inner cmd process. So if i put it like this: CMD /c set VAR=foo & cmd /c echo %VAR% then it works fine.